# What does this symbol mean next to my characters name on the character select screen?

Tags: new-world

I noticed this symbol (circled) next to my characters name in New World:

[image]

It looks like a snake or maybe a dragon within a green shield.  What does this symbol mean? Clicking the ellipsis below it doesn't tell you anything - that is for "Character Options."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the symbol of the company you are apart of, as indicative of the company overview tab of the company you apart of in the game menus:

[image: company symbol]

You will also see this symbol next to all of the members who are apart of the company (and a similar type of symbol indicating the company other players are apart of).